# Javascript: contat string and integer without the " between the integer

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-google-maps

Anyone knows how to concat in js a string with a integer and don't get the ":

This

`"<agm-map latitude=" + response.latitude + " longitude=" + response.longitude + "></agm-map>";`

Results on

`<agm-map [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007"></agm-map>`

But I'm trying to get without the ", as I show bellow

```
<agm-map [latitude]=51.678418 [longitude]=7.809007></agm-map>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `"test" + 5 === "test5"` - someone might have a crystal orb and know what you want, but "concat string with integer" does not magically produce quotes.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to produce an HTML snippet. In which case, the browser is likely adding the quotes around the values automatically.

Comment: fubar, it's exactly that. Do you know how do I insert the text on html without adding the quotes?

Comment: @AlexandreBento Yes, it is exactly that, and you can’t change it. Parsing, then serializing your desired HTML string yields `<agm-map [latitude]="51.678418" [longitude]="7.809007"></agm-map>`, because this is the only valid way to write these attributes. For reference: `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(new DOMParser().parseFromString('<agm-map [latitude]=51.678418 [longitude]=7.809007></agm-map>', "text/html"))`.

Comment: @AlexandreBento - you can't. The browser is going to treat all HTML attributes as a string. You'd need to parse the value in your JS (assuming) back to a float.

Comment: What do you mean fubar? I'm sorry, but I didn't understood that parse the value back to float

Comment: `<agm-map>` element isn't a standard HTML element. So I assume you're using it with a JavaScript framework (e.g. React, Angular, Vue). That being the case, when you get the element properties, before you use the `latitude` and `longitude`, cast the value from a `string` to a `float`.

Comment: I'm using Angular, I was searching for a way to use maps on my api, I found that `<agm-map>`, on my problem I use http://freegeoip.net/json/ to get one json with some data about my IP include the latitude and longitude, so I need to use those values to show my location on a map. My code is just that:

Comment: `function getLocation() {
 $.ajax({
  type : 'GET',
  url : 'http://freegeoip.net/json/' + document.getElementById('domain').value,
  success : function(response){
   var test = "<agm-map [latitude]=" + response.latitude + " [longitude]=" + response.longitude + "></agm-map>";
   document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = test;
  }
 });
}`

my code is just that... :(

Answer (score 1):

Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities. [Reference Link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

[JSbin Link](http://jsbin.com/culoxuwelo/2/edit?html,js,output)

> Code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  //replace lat & lng value with the response
  var latitude = 51.678418;
  var longitude = 7.809007;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML="&lt;agm-map [latitude=]" + latitude + " [longitude]=" + longitude + "&gt;&lt;/agm-map&gt;";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>
    <p id="demo">Change text</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Now I understand, Reserved characters in HTML must be replaced with character entities, see my revised code above.